# Using CertPathBuilder and PKIX with non-X509 certificates

Tags: java, x509, pkix

I'm working with [Card Verifiable Certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_Verifiable_Certificate) in Java (using PrimeKey/EJBCA's [cert-cvc library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ejbca/files/cert-cvc/cert-cvc-1.3.0/)) which are non-X.509 certificates, yet they implement `java.security.cert.Certificate`.

I would like to use the existing chain building algorithms, i.e. using `CertPathBuilder` and its PKIX implementation (in either Oracle/Sun's security provider or Bouncy Castle's) to build chains of these CVC certs. I'm currently stuck in using `PKIXBuilderParameters` with my set of trustanchors, as it apparently expects X.509 certs.

Is there a way use non-X.509 certificates with PKIX? If not, is there a way to use `CertPathBuilder` with non-X.509 certificates without having to implement my own custom `CertBuilderSpi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a `PKIX certpath builder` is not applicable for CVC. Verifying paths according to `PKIX (rfc5280)` is very x.509 specific including things like name constraints, certificate policy extensions etc. This is probably why the trustanchors requires x.509 certs.

The only option I could think of that does not require you to implement a custom `CertBuilderSpi` would be if BC had one for CVC, since it also implements other CVC certificates.

But a quick search:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec grep -H "extends CertPathBuilderSpi" {} \;
```

reveals only the `PKIX` classes. And cert-cvc also does not implement a `CertPathBuilder`. Such an addition would be cool though.

Cheers,
Tomas

Comment: I was afraid of that... Thanks!